# How can i use infinite scroll in react native reversed flatlist

Tags: reactjs, react-native, chat, infinite-scroll, react-native-flatlist

I want to build chat app, baceuse of i need load messages by infinite scrolling but there is a problem. When i use flatlist i cant handle fetchmore time baceuse i have to use inverted flatlist. Baceuse of i can't use onendReach method in flatlist.
What is the way to do that?

```
<FlatList 
   data={data.chatDetail.edges}
   keyExtractor={(item, index)=>String(index)}
   renderItem={({item})=>{
       return(<TopicMain style={styles.topicMain} data={item}/>)
   }}
   inverted={true}
   />
```

Answer (score 0):

i use it currently

```
// get before topreach 5.th item
const thresouldVal = data.chatDetail.edges.slice(-5)
const reachIds = thresouldVal.map(val => val._id)
const handleLoadMore = useCallback((lastViewableItem) => {
    // check is top reach
    const isTopReach = reachIds.includes(lastViewableItem.item._id)
    if (isTopReach) {
        // fetchMore
    }
}, [reachIds],
)
```

Flatlist

```
 <FlatList
    data={data.chatDetail.edges}
    keyExtractor={(item, index) => String(index)}
    renderItem={({ item }) => {
       return (<TopicMain style={styles.topicMain} data={item} />)}}
    inverted={true}
    onViewableItemsChanged={({ viewableItems, changed }) =>{handleLoadMore(viewableItems.slice(-1)[0]) }}
        />
```